# Resizing a vector by interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, vector, resize, torch

I want to resize a vector by interpolating.

Torch happen to have a function to do that, but it does not work for 1D vectors !!
[Interpolate](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.interpolate.html#torch.nn.functional.interpolate)

```
 In [25]: torch.nn.functional.interpolate(torch.randn(5),10)


 NotImplementedError: Input Error: Only 3D, 4D and 5D input Tensors supported (got 1D) for the modes: nearest | linear | bilinear | bicubic | trilinear | area | nearest-exact (got nearest)
```

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seem to work ... thanks @markoj

```
In [70]: z=torch.randn(5)[None,None,:]

In [71]: z
Out[71]: tensor([[[ 0.90,  0.83, -1.57, -2.07,  0.99]]])

In [72]: torch.nn.functional.interpolate(z,10)
Out[72]: tensor([[[ 0.90,  0.90,  0.83,  0.83, -1.57, -1.57, -2.07, -2.07,  0.99,  0.99]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of vector you are talking about since you did not provide much info. However, I think you should check out [scipy's interpolate package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html)

Comment: looked at BicubicSpline, cause wanted to use bicubic but it returns something else not vector ... have to read more on splines

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just extend it to 3D using `np.expand_dims`, and the reduce it back to 1D with `[0][0]`. More specifically:

```py
tensor.tensor(
torch.nn.functional.interpolate(
tensor.tensor(numpy.expand_dims(torch.randn(5).numpy(),axis=2))
,10).numpy()[0][0])
```